# My custom linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I've tried to create my best at creating a custom Linked List implementation in C++.  This is my code, would love to get feedback on it!

`DATA_TYPE` is a macro defined elsewhere.

```
struct Node
{
  DATA_TYPE data;
  Node *next;
};

void addEnd(DATA_TYPE value, Node *&head, Node *&tail)
{
  Node *newNode = new Node;
  newNode->data = value;
  newNode->next = nullptr;
  if (head == nullptr) head = tail = newNode; 
  else {
    tail->next = newNode;
    tail = newNode;
  }
}

void addBeginning(DATA_TYPE value, Node *&head, Node *&tail)
{
  Node *newNode = new Node;
  newNode->data = value;
  if (head == nullptr) {
    newNode->next = nullptr;
    head = tail = newNode;
  } else {
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
  }
}

void addSpecific(DATA_TYPE value, DATA_TYPE location, Node *&head, Node *&tail)
{
  Node *newNode = new Node;
  newNode->data = value;
  if (head == nullptr) {
    newNode->next = nullptr;
    head = tail = newNode;
  } else {
    Node *temp = head;
    while (temp->data != location) {
      if (temp->next == nullptr) {
        std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\t" << "LL-> Node (" << location << ") Not Found In The List.";
        std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
        return;
      }
      temp = temp->next;
    }
    newNode->next = temp->next;
    temp->next = newNode;
    if (temp->next == nullptr) tail = newNode;
  }
}

void deleteBeginning(Node *&head)
{
  if (head == nullptr) {
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t" << "LL-> The List Is Empty. Deletion Not Possible.";
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    return;
  }
  Node *temp = head;
  if (temp->next == nullptr) {
    head = nullptr;
    delete temp;
  } else {
    head = head->next;
    delete temp;
  }
}

void deleteEnd(Node *&head, Node *&tail)
{
  if (head == nullptr) {
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t" << "LL-> The List Is Empty. Deletion Not Possible.";
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    return;
  }
  Node *temp = head;
  if (temp->next == nullptr) {
    head = nullptr;
    delete temp;
  } else {
    while (temp->next != tail) temp = temp->next;
    tail = temp;
    temp = temp->next;
    tail->next = nullptr;
    delete temp;
  }
}

void deleteSpecific(DATA_TYPE node_location, Node *&head, Node *&tail)
{
  if (head == nullptr) {
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t" << "LL-> The List Is Empty. Deletion Not Possible.";
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    return;
  }
  Node *temp1 = head, *temp2;
  while (temp1->data != node_location) {
      if (temp1->next == nullptr) {
      std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
      std::cout << "\t" << "LL-> Given Node Not Found. Deletion Not Possible.";
      std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
      return;
    }
    temp2 = temp1;
    temp1 = temp1->next;
  }

  if (temp1->data == node_location) {
    if (head == temp1 && tail == temp1) {
      head = nullptr;
      delete temp1;
    } else if (temp1 == head) {
      head = head->next;
      delete temp1;
    } else if (temp1 == tail) {
      temp2->next = nullptr;
      tail = temp2;
      delete temp1;
    } else {
      temp2->next = temp1->next;
      delete temp1;
    }
  }
}

void display(Node *head)
{
  if (head == nullptr) {
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t" << "LL-> The List Is Empty.";
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    return;
  }
  Node *temp = head;
  std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << "\t" << "| ";
  while (temp != nullptr) {
    std::cout << temp->data << " | ";
    temp = temp->next;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: _"`DATA_TYPE`
is a macro defined elsewhere!"_ Why not using a template class instead? All in all that more looks like c-code, than c++.

Comment: πάντα-ῥεῖ, I've actually thought about it, does it make big difference? What are the pros of actually using a template class?

Comment: _"What are the pros of actually using a template class?"_ That it's generic?

Comment: ok, that's enough, I'm convinced :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One thing that I don't like is code such as the following whenever you deal with an empty container:

```
std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
std::cout << "\t" << "LL-> Node (" << location << ") Not Found In The List.";
std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
```

When you move your code into a class, as @πάντα ῥεῖ said, then you should probably [throw](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw) an exception (You can make your own class and inherit it from [`std::exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception)) instead of `cout`ing something. Otherwise, your function is given too many responsibilites, and not all applications for a linked list have a console to output to.

The other thing I don't like is this conditional:

```
if (head == temp1 && tail == temp1) {
  head = nullptr;
  delete temp1;
} else if (temp1 == head) {
  head = head->next;
  delete temp1;
} else if (temp1 == tail) {
  temp2->next = nullptr;
  tail = temp2;
  delete temp1;
} else {
  temp2->next = temp1->next;
  delete temp1;
}
```

Notice how there is a `delete temp1` at the end of every one of those conditionals. That breaks the [D.R.Y](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle. Make the `delete temp1` unconditional.

Answer (score 6):

You should provide a (template) `class` to encapsulate the inner states (`head`, `tail`) of a linked list, instead of a bunch of *free functions* and the `Node` structure. Something like:

```
template <typename DataType>
class LinkedList {
    // The Node doesn't need to be seen publicly
    struct Node {
        DataType data;
        Node *next;
    };

    Node* head;
    Node* tail;

public:
    LinkedList() : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) {}
    Node* addEnd(DataType value);
    Node* addBeginning(DataType value);
    // ...
    void deleteSpecific(Node*);
};

template <typename DataType>
LinkedList<DataType>::Node* LinkedList::addEnd(DataType value) {
   // Implementation ...
}

template <typename DataType>
LinkedList<DataType>::Node* LinkedList::addBeginning(DataType value); {
   // Implementation ...
}

template <typename DataType>
void deleteSpecific(LinkedList<DataType>::Node* node) {
   // Implementation ...
}
```

Clients of the `LinkedList` class may use the `auto` keyword to keep variables of the private `LinkedList<DataType>::Node` structure:

```
LinkedList<int> ll;
auto item1 = ll.addEnd(5);
auto item2 = ll.addBeginning(42);
ll.deleteSpecific(item1);
```